# Validate the length of a char * taken from std::cin

Tags: c++, validation, pointers, iostream

I have a pointer called `char * panimal_name`. This pointer should only be able to take in 20 characters and if the user enters more, it must ask the user to re-enter.

I've tried counting the characters in the stream and also using `strlen()`, however I'm still having problems.

```
cout << "Enter Animal Name: ";
cin.ignore();
cin.getline(panimal_name, 20);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** Well I only want it to take at most 20 characters from the user.  If that 20 is exceeded it should then ask the user to re-enter valid input.  However in this setup, it now messes up the stream for my next inputs. The reason I'm using this, rather than a `std::string`, is that I'm learning pointers at the moment.

P.S. I know a string would probably be better in this situation for ease of use.

Comment: What problems are you having?

Comment: Is there any reason why you aren't using a string ?

Comment: @DumbCoder: for some reason, schools and universities absolutely don't want students using string data types.  They chant the mantra of "char *".  (Also, there's almost never a mention of any part of the STL)

Comment: If you want a more C-like solution, try this: `scanf("%20s", panimal_name); ungetc('x', stdin); scanf("%*s");`

Answer (score 1):

You can use c++ methods..

```
std::string somestring;

std::cout << "Enter Animal Name: ";
std::cin >> somestring;

printf("someString = %s, and its length is %lu", somestring.c_str(), strlen(somestring.c_str()));
```

you can also use more c++ methods

```
std::string somestring;

std::cout << "Enter Animal Name: ";
std::cin >> somestring;

std::cout << "animal is: "<< somestring << "and is of length: " << somestring.length();
```

I guess you could do something with cin to a stringstream to get around the way that cin exctract works.

Comment: Could you please expand on that last remark? How does cin extract differently from other streams?

Comment: A bit ironic how you say “use C++ methods” and then use `printf`. ;-)

Comment: konrad... yeah i could just remove that part.. rob, let me try a little something with code... the normal extract behavior only goes basically to the next space... you can do that recursively while not at end...

Comment: never mind rob, your example is better... and a more modern c++ practice .

Answer (score 1):

According to MSDN:

> If the function extracts no elements or _Count - 1 elements, it calls
>   setstate(failbit)...

You could check for that failbit to see if the user entered more data than the buffer allows?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>

// The easy way
std::string f1() {
  std::string result;
  do {
    std::cout << "Enter Animal Name: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, result);
  } while(result.size() == 0 || result.size() > 20);
  return result;
}

// The hard way
void f2(char *panimal_name) {
  while(1) {
    std::cout << "Enter Animal Name: ";
    std::cin.getline(panimal_name, 20);
    // getline can fail it is reaches EOF. Not much to do now but give up
    if(std::cin.eof())
      return;
    // If getline succeeds, then we can return
    if(std::cin)
      return;
    // Otherwise, getline found too many chars before '\n'. Try again,
    // but we have to clear the errors first.
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
  }
}

int main () {
  std::cout << "The easy way\n";
  std::cout << f1() << "\n\n";

  std::cout << "The hard way\n";
  char animal_name[20];
  f2(animal_name);
  std::cout << animal_name << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a larger buffer for user input and check for the last element of your buffer.